# Zend Framework accessing controllers through URLs

Tags: zend-framework, url, controllers

I am starting to learn Zend Framework with book Beginning Zend Framework (Apress), I have trouble aceesing different controllers through URL. I setup the directory structure for Zend Framework and setup Apache2.2\htdocs\testproject\public as the default for localhost. If i try to access a different controller by typing localhost/new I get a 404(Not Found).

My directory structure looks like this:

```
htdocs
--testproject
----application
------configs
------controllers
--------IndexController.php
--------NewController.php
------models
------views
------Bootstrap.php
----docs
----library
----public
----tests
----.zfproject.xml
```

Comment: have you verified your .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have enabled apache's `rewrite` module.
2. Make sure you have `AllowOverride All` in your `httpd.conf` settings.

Can you confirm above points and restart your apache and try once again? I am sure you won't face this problem again.